# How to define WP_DEBUG as true outside of wp-config.php?

Tags: wp-debug

I am trying to create a debugging mode in one of my plugins so users can easily enable WP_DEBUG on their own, and hopefully report back to us with helpful error messages. Right now we ask them to modify their wp-config.php, but that's beyond some users' capabilities. I was hoping to just add `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`in our plugin if the user has checked that option, but it appears you can only enable WP_DEBUG from the wp-config.php file.

Does anyone know of any way to enable WP_DEBUG from anywhere else but wp-config? Or is there another useful WP function that I could be using instead?

Thanks,
Dalton

Comment: Guess what, I tried the exact same thing a couple of days back, but didn't work. And if there was a way, then an option to turn on/off the debug mode via the dashboard would've been there cause editing the config is very risky! Anyways you can try this way: http://www.wordpressluv.com/how-to-easily-enabledisable-debug-mode-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks Rutwick, that link is super helpful. Won't work for me in this case (I need to be able to display errors without editing wp-config.php) but I can see this coming in very handy.

Comment: You're welcome @Dalton! If you find a way, please let me know too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WordPress logic forces `WP_DEBUG` to be defined to *something*, even if it's omitted it will be set to `false` in [`wp_initial_constants()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_initial_constants) during load.

However "background" (that is not when it is checked explicitly) function of `WP_DEBUG` is to be a flag for how PHP error reporting should be configured on runtime. That configuration is performed by [`wp_debug_mode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_debug_mode/) and at any point after that can be changed by your plugin's code if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for that background info, I did not know about wp_debug_mode(). Even when changed after the fact, it still cannot override the initial setting of WP_DEBUG in the wp-config, can it?

Comment: @Dalton correct, you can't change constant itself, but you can easily change error reporting settings.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to turn on `WP_DEBUG` because it's defined in wp-config.php by default, redefinition of defined [constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) is not possible in PHP.

If you want to keep them out of *wp-config.php* ask them to add to the top something like:

```
if ( file_exists( 'safe-wp-config.php' ) ) {
    /* this will contains WP_DEBUG */
    include 'safe-wp-config.php';
}
```

Alternatively,

[`WP_DEBUG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) is assumed to be `false` when missing, so let them remove `WP_DEBUG` completely from *wp-config.php* and use wherever/whenever they like.

Comment: it's possible with [runkit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-constant-redefine.php)

Comment: @onetrickpony Thanks for the tip but I need some advice. Why wouldn't something along these lines work (added in my theme's functions.php)?

runkit_constant_redefine( 'WP_DEBUG' , true ); 
runkit_constant_add( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); 
runkit_constant_add( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have access to `wp-config.php` but you do have access to the theme (or plugin) editor, you can add a code snippet to essentially do the same thing as the `WP_DEBUG` constant.  The `wp_debug_mode()` function uses the value of this and a few other constants to set the display and log error functions in PHP.  You can run the same PHP functions directly with actually touching the `WP_DEBUG` constant or the `wp-config.php` file.

Here are the key PHP functions your code snippet can use:

- `error_reporting( E_ALL )` - sets PHP to display all errors, warnings, and notices.
- `ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 )` - sets PHP to display errors on the screen; use 0 to supress (although if debugging is not enabled in `wp-config.php` this will already be 0 so you could omit it altogether).
- `ini_set( 'log_errors', 1)` - sets PHP to log errors. Like the value above, this can be omitted if you're not going to log errors. If you do log errors, you'll need an error log you can get to. The default set by `wp_debug_mode()` is going to be inaccessible. My example will set it as a text file in the theme directory so you can read it with the theme editor.
- `ini_set( 'error_log', $log_path )` - sets the location of the error log (mentioned above).

Here's the code snippet:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_enable_debug_mode' );
function my_enable_debug_mode() {

    // Turn on error reporting.
    error_reporting( E_ALL );

    // Sets to display errors on screen. Use 0 to turn off.
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );

    // Sets to log errors. Use 0 (or omit) to not log errors.
    ini_set( 'log_errors', 1 );

    // Sets a log file path you can access in the theme editor.
    $log_path = get_template_directory() . '/debug.txt';
    ini_set( 'error_log', $log_path );

}
```

To summarize, if you need to debug, do not have access to `wp-config.php` but do have access to the theme editor, you can add this code snippet to the `functions.php` file to enable debugging on screen along with a txt log file in the theme folder.

Comment: Nice practical solution, just a minor issue with the code, you are missing the parentheses to make get_template_directory a function call. I also used the init hook so this works in the admin pages too.

Comment: Thanks @terraling.  I've updated it.

Answer (score 1):

However, if you really want to display errors and not store them in log file (like I wanted), then you can turn on debugging for your Public IP like following -

```
if ( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

There should not be a problem as long as you are on Static IP, but if you have dynamic IP, you probably can change the IP every time you need to turn on debugigng.

Answer (score 1):

I am very late to the party. However, I had a requirement where I had to enable wp_debug and I had no access to the files. This plugin helped: https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug/

Maybe you can do the same thing as the plugin? Edit wp-config.php programmatically?